# How to let a user choose a directory using python streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I would like to develop a web app that lets the user choose a directory from his computer and then do some computation on the files in the chosen directory. The only thing I found so far is the file_uploader streamlit function but I dont want to upload anything.
I would also like to let the user choose a single file without uploading it, just need it's name and location to do some computation.

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit does not support folder picker and file picker. Even the upload button does not tell the folder name, only the filename.

To accomplish what you want, just create text_input, and let the user type the folder path.

For example:

`c:/project`

Then you can attempt to validate it if it is a folder and if so, scan the files in this folder. The scanned files can then be used as an option in selectbox.

```py
import os
import streamlit as st

folder_path = st.text_input('Input folder path')

# Scan the folder with files.
file_paths = []
if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
    for fn in os.listdir(folder_path):
        fp = f'{folder_path}/{fn}'
        if os.path.isfile(fp):
            file_paths.append(fp)

# Select file from scanned folder.
selected_file = st.selectbox('Select file', options=file_paths)
st.write(f'selected file: {selected_file}')
```

### Output

[image]